# SharePoint 2010 configuration fails

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, configuration-wizard

Wizard fails at step 3.

I should mention that the account I'm logged in with is in the local admin group, the farm admin group, and has sysadmin/DB creator for the SharePoint config database.

I have also configured the SQL alias to be the same on the new server as it is on the other farm servers.

[image]

**ERROR MESSAGE FROM UDL TEST:**

[image]

Comment: can you ping the sql server from the SharePoint server?

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all , try to open the mentioned log to can trace the root cause of the issue , besides to the following points that you need to check

- Make sure the SQL Server services is running.
- Make sure you are set the SQL alias with the correct IP.

[image]

- Make sure that the Application server can reach to Database server by creating a UDL file as mentioned at [Creating and Configuring Universal Data Link (.udl) Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rcormier/2012/10/24/you-shall-configure-your-maxdop-when-using-sharepoint-2013/)
- Make sure that in database server the `max degree of parallelism = 1`for more details check [You Shall Configure your MAXDOP When Using SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rcormier/2012/10/24/you-shall-configure-your-maxdop-when-using-sharepoint-2013/)

[image]

- Make sure The Firewall is not blocking the communication to DB server (default  port 1433)

For more details check [SharePoint 2013: Troubleshooting - Cannot Connect to the Configuration Database](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6545.sharepoint-2013-troubleshooting-cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database.aspx)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm adding a server to a farm that is already configured and running. I've checked everything above and it all appears to be configured correctly.

Comment: are you opened the log and checked it ? should you share with us what you got ?

Comment: are you tried UDL file from application server and tried to connect to sql server ?

Comment: I was doing the UDL test from the wrong server. Doing the test on the new server failed. I will attach a screenshot above.

Comment: so now the application server can't reach database server , should you make sure you have provided the right DB server IP in your alias ? how many database server you have ?

Comment: check the network connection between the application server and database server , check that the firewall is not blocking the SQL server port  ? and tell me result , hope it help you